# Writing a print method in C

Tags: c, pointers, scheme, interpreter

I am new to C and working on making an interpreter for Scheme. I am trying to get a suitable printList method to traverse through the structure.

The program takes in an input like:

> (a (b c))

and internally represent it as:

```
[""][ ][ ]-->  [""][ ][/]
     |              |              
   ["A"][/][/]     [""][ ][ ]-->  [""][ ][/]     
                        |              |                 
                      ["B"][/][/]    ["C"][/][/]
```

Right now, I just want the program to take in the input, make the appropriate cell structure internally and print out the cell structure, thereby getting

> (a (b c))

at the end.

Here is my struct:

```
typedef struct conscell *List;

struct conscell {
char symbol;
struct conscell *first;
struct conscell *rest;

};


void printList(char token[20]){
    List current = S_Expression(token, 0);

     printf("(");

printf("First Value? %c \n", current->first->symbol);
printf("Second value? %c \n", current->rest->first->first->symbol);
printf("Third value? %c \n", current->rest->first->rest->first->symbol);


printf(")");

}
```

In the main method, I get the first token and call:

> printList(token);

**I tested the values again for the sublists and I think it is working. However, I will need a method to traverse through the whole structure. Please look at my printList code again. The print calls are what I have to type, to manually get the (a (b c)) list values. So I get this output:**

> First value? a
>
> First value? b
>
> First value? c

It is what I want, but I want a method to do it using a loop, no matter how complex the structure is, also adding brackets where appropriate, so in the end, I should get:

> (a (b c))

which is the same as the input.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: the type of List is a pointer of struct conscell, therefore should the malloc be of sizeof(struct conscell) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the type of List is a pointer of struct conscell, therefore should the malloc() in your createList function be of sizeof(struct conscell):

```
List node = malloc(sizeof(struct conscell));
```

the pointer to the structure is only 8 byte, whereas the size of the structure itself is 17 (with default padding actually 24byte):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Comment: Thank you so much for your help in fixing that. It makes more sense now. 
Can you also look at the updated question and see if you can find the root problem?

Comment: @RehanRasool After fixing your allocation size as noted above, you may want to plug the memory leaks in your program as well. `List` is a pointer type, and `temp = createList();` followed immediately by `temp = local;` is a direct memory leak in two short lines.

Comment: @WhozCraig good point. I only was looking at the createList() function yet.

Comment: @RehanRasool could you also post the getToken() function and main method of your program as well? the strcpys in the function S_Expression also slightly worrying...

Comment: @TanukiSoftware I think that will be a lot of information that you might not want to go through. 
getToken just gets the next string in the input line.
For example, if I input: (a b c)
the first strcpy(token, getToken) call, copies '(' to token. Next time, it copies 'a' to token, next time it copies 'b' to token and so on.
If you'd still like to see it, I can upload it. 
Secondly, right now the assignment does not require me to deal with memory loss, so I am not worried about it. 
Thank you for the replies so far!

Comment: @TanukiSoftware I have gone through the code again and it looks to be working fine. However, I need a printList method to traverse through the entire structure and print everything. 
(Please look at the question again, I updated it.) Can you help me with it?

Comment: @RehanRasool glad you got it figured out. that's a normal generic tree traversal, so there should be many examples out, where you can check for additional information

Comment: @TanukiSoftware Oh! I never looked at it that way. It looks like a tree with two nodes and a data field. I am still wondering how to traverse through it without recursion but I will try figuring something out by myself.
Thank you so much!

Comment: @TanukiSoftware I just have a minute problem, if you can help me with it. 
My program just takes the first character of whatever the input token is and displays it. For example input of ( rehan is learning ) will have an output of just ( r i l ). How can I fix that to take in the whole word? I am pretty sure getToken returns the whole word, it is probably the char symbol in the struct conscell that cuts it down. Can you help me with it?

Comment: @RehanRasool: Yes, your `symbol` is just one character, and contains the first character of a token: `cell->symbol = *token;`. You need to have symbols longer than just one character.

Answer (score 2):

The original program's datatype is slightly weird; you want to be able to describe a disjoint set of data, in which case a **union** is probably what you want.  At the moment, you've only got a single datatype for cons cells, which makes it difficult to distinguish between:

```
(a b c)
```

and

```
(a (b c))
```

The trick you're using right now is to treat symbolic data as one where both the left and right pointers of your cell are NULL, but that makes it impossible to represent:

```
(())
```

which is exactly what happens when you have a cons cell whose contents are both NULL.

One way you might represent a disjoint set of data is to use a tagged disjoint union, like this:

```
enum SexpType {SYMBOL, CONS, NIL};

struct Sexp {
  enum SexpType type;
  union {
    char symbol;
    struct Cons *cons;
  };
};

struct Cons {
  struct Sexp *first;
  struct Sexp *rest;
};
```

An Sexp can either be a `SYMBOL`, a `CONS`, or `NIL`.  Depending on its type, we'll treat the union part of the structure differently.

We might include a few helpers to make it easier to construct these kind of structures:

```
struct Sexp* newCons(struct Sexp* first, struct Sexp* rest) {
  struct Sexp* pair = malloc(sizeof(struct Sexp));
  pair->type = CONS;
  pair->cons = malloc(sizeof(struct Cons));
  pair->cons->first = first;
  pair->cons->rest = rest;
  return pair;
}

struct Sexp* newSymbol(char c) {
  struct Sexp* ch = malloc(sizeof(struct Sexp));
  ch->type = SYMBOL;
  ch->symbol = c;
  return ch;
}
```

Once we have the proper data representation, then `printList` will be a recursive function that dispatches based on the the type tag:

```
void printSexp(struct Sexp* sexp) {
  switch (sexp->type) {
  case SYMBOL: 
    /* FIXME */
    break;
  case CONS:
    /* FIXME */
    break;
  case NIL:
    /* FIXME */
    break;
  }
}
```

where each of the cases are fairly simple.  To get the `CONS` case to do something, we might try something like this:

```
printf("(");
printSexp(sexp->cons->first);
printf(" . ");
printSexp(sexp->cons->rest);
printf(")");
```

where we recursively call the printer on the components of the pair.  However, this might not be exactly what we want, since it treats everything as an improper structure, and you may want to do something nicer for regular lists.